# calculate distance and show route on google map with waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-distancematrix-api

I am working on the web app in Which I need to add pickup address, drop-off address and a array of visit area through which user will move between pickup and drop-off address. What I have done is route the map and calculate the distance between pickup and dropoff address, but I am unable to match the visit areas with pickup and drop-off.
Here is my code, If I anyone can give me an idea how to do this:

**web Form**

```
<form class="uk-form" name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input id="pickup" class="controls" name="pickup" type="text"/>
<input id="dropoff" class="controls" name="dropoff" type="text"/>
<input id="visitarea" class="controls" name="visitarea" type="text"/>    
<input id="calculatefare" class="calculatefare" type="button" value="Calculate Fare" />
</form>
```

**Javascript Function**

```
function initAutocomplete() {

var origin_place_id = null;
var destination_place_id = null;
var visitarea_place_id = null;

var travel_mode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
  mapTypeControl: false,
  center: {lat: 30.3753, lng: 69.3451},
  zoom: 7,
  scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false
});

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var pickup = document.getElementById('pickup');
var dropoff = document.getElementById('dropoff');
var visitarea = document.getElementById('visitarea');


var options = {
componentRestrictions: {country: 'pk'}//Pakistan only
};

var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup,options);
origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(dropoff,options);
destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(visitarea,options);
destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.

function expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place) {
  if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
  } else {
    map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(17);
  }
}

origin_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  var place = origin_autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }
  expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

  // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
  // the other place ID
  origin_place_id = place.place_id;
  route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, visitarea_place_id, travel_mode,
        directionsService, directionsDisplay);
});

destination_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  var place = destination_autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }
  expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

  // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
  // the other place ID
  destination_place_id = place.place_id;
  route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, visitarea_place_id, travel_mode,
        directionsService, directionsDisplay);
});

visitarea_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
  var place = visitarea_autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.geometry) {
    window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
    return;
  }
  expandViewportToFitPlace(map, place);

  // If the place has a geometry, store its place ID and route if we have
  // the other place ID
  visitarea_place_id = place.place_id;
  route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, visitarea_place_id, travel_mode,
        directionsService, directionsDisplay);
});

function route(origin_place_id, destination_place_id, visitarea_place_id, travel_mode,
               directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  if (!origin_place_id || !destination_place_id) {
    return;
  }


  directionsService.route({
    origin: {'placeId': origin_place_id},
    destination: {'placeId': destination_place_id},
    visitarea: {'placeId': visitarea_place_id},
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: travel_mode
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var d = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        document.getElementById('km').value = d;


    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}

 }
```

This code is not working due to the visit areas input field in web form and all other related stuff in javascript function but if I remove all the visit area related stuff, the pick and drop-off address working fine and the give me the required output.

Any help in this ?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I notice, your variable for your `dropoff` and `visitarea` is the same. It will replace the older value with the newer one, in your case the value will be the `visitarea`.

Kindly check the [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) for direction and waypoints demonstrates the use of the `DirectionsService` object to fetch directions for a route including waypoints.

Read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) for more information about using waypoints in routes.

Here is a snippet of the sample with some of your code:

**FORM**

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
<div>
<b>Start:</b><input id="pickup" class="controls" name="pickup" type="text"/>
<br>
<b>Waypoints:</b> <br>
<input id="visitarea" class="controls" name="visitarea" type="text"/>
<br>
<b>End:</b>
<input id="dropoff" class="controls" name="dropoff" type="text"/>
<br>
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</div>
<div id="directions-panel"></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function initMap() {
    var origin_place_id = null;
    var destination_place_id = null;
    var visitarea_place_id = null;

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });

    var pickup = document.getElementById('pickup');
    var dropoff = document.getElementById('dropoff');
    var visitarea = document.getElementById('visitarea');

    var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'pk'}//Pakistan only
    };

    var origin_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(pickup,options);
    origin_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var destination_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(dropoff,options);
    destination_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var visitarea_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(visitarea,options);
    visitarea_autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);


    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, origin_autocomplete, visitarea_autocomplete, destination_autocomplete);
      console.log(origin_autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address + " "+ destination_autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address + " "+ visitarea_autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address);
    });

  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, start, waypoint, end) {


    var waypts = [];
        waypts.push({
          location: waypoint.getPlace().formatted_address,
          stopover: true
        });


    directionsService.route({
      origin: start.getPlace().formatted_address,
      destination: end.getPlace().formatted_address,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment +
              '</b><br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Very nice! Throws an error if you don't enter a waypoint, but other than that, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Hyderabad+Telangana+India&destinations=Mumbai+Maharashtra+India';
$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array
$mi = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
$km = $mi*1.60934;
echo round($km)." KM <br/>";
echo $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text'];
```